# Lot of issues with Eclipse mars and java-openjdk8 under ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-16.04

Are there any known issues regarding Eclipse Mars (4.5.2) under Ubuntu Mate 16.04 and java-openjdk8?

-Since upgrade, the GUI is responding VERY slow (a real handicap so far, taking away all the coding fun)..
To be more specific, for example, any hover mouse-action does not work unless waiting several time with cursor on the text.

-And the console does not update itself sometimes.. Which mean, if i run, i have to change the view and change it back (e.g. click on 'snippets'-tab and then on 'console' again.
-If the console print any links to classes (e.g. in error-logs) They do not work until i change the view again (which means click on the link-->click on the tab 'snippets'. Then the linked class gets opened.

It's so strange that i think of downgrade again (ubuntu15.10, java-openjdk7) But i also upgraded to android studio 2.1 which needs java8 jdk..

Edit:

- Codecompletion does not work. I wonder wtf? Simply nothing works.
  All issues are temporary thus not to reproduce or to describe more detailed.. Its very very unstable.
  Did i miss something? Is some of the listed software incompatible?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio and Eclipse, I would suggest just using IntelliJ IDEA. No guarantees that'll fix any instability you are experiencing.

Comment: i've got used to eclipse and want to keep using it for my pure-java apps... but yes... if it not will get better i have to think about it..

Comment: I switched to IntelliJ about 2 years ago. Overall, I like it better than Eclipse, but that's just my opinion

Comment: Yes it does not really makes sence to use more than one - so far redundant - IDEs... i know use intellij for both Java and Android. Thank you

Comment: Instead of updating, just download a fresh zip of the new release and use that.

Comment: yes I handled it like that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the problems due to new GTK3 library/default theme used. Switch to GTK2 will resolve the problems. See this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=492371).

How to force [eclipse to use GTK2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761604/eclipse-not-working-in-16-04)